# Unexpected behavior after assignment of function object to function wrapper

Tags: c++, c++11, object-slicing

I was searching a bug in an application, which I've finally fixed but didn't understand completely. 
The behavior can be reproduced with the following simple program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

struct Foo
{
  virtual int operator()(void) { return 1; } 
};

struct Bar : public Foo
{
  virtual int operator()(void) override { return 2; }
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> p = std::make_shared<Bar>();
    std::cout << (*p)() << std::endl;

    std::function<int(void)> f;
    f = *p;
    std::cout << f() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the line

> ```cpp
> std::cout << (*p)() << std::endl;
> ```

is `2`, which is as I expected, of course.

But the output of the line

> ```cpp
> std::cout << f() << std::endl;
> ```

is `1`. This was surprising me. I even was surprised that the assignment `f = *p` is allowed and doesn't cause an error.

I don't ask for a workaround, because I fixed it by a lambda.
My question is, what is happening when I do `f = *p` and why is the output `1` rather than `2`?

I've reproduced the issue with gcc (MinGW) and Visual Studio 2019.
Further I want to mention that the output of

```cpp
Bar b;
std::function<int(void)> f1 = b;
std::cout << f1() << std::endl;
```

is `2`, again.

Comment: I wonder what you expected to happen in the guts of std::function for it to result in a call to Bar::opeeator(). How should the assignment have worked?

Comment: @n.m. I didn't expect anything, it was a bug, which I had to find in some code which was not written by me.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Object slicing happens here.

The point is given `f = *p;`, `p` is of type `std::shared_ptr<Foo>`, then the type of `*p` is `Foo&` (instead of `Bar&`). Even the [assignment operator of `std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator%3D) takes argument by reference, but

> 4) Sets the target of `*this` to the callable `f`, as if by executing `function(std::forward<F>(f)).swap(*this);`.

Note that the `F` above is deduced as `Foo&` too. And the [constructor of `std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function) takes argument by value, object slicing happens, the effect becomes that `f` is assigned from an object of type `Foo` which is slice-copied from `*p`.

> ```
> template< class F > 
> function( F f );
> ```

Answer (score 12):

This is regular slicing, hidden under a layer of `std::function` and `std::shared_ptr`.

```
f = *p;
```

is valid because `*p` is a callable object with an appropriate `operator()`, and that is one of the things you can wrap in a `std::function`.

The reason that it doesn't work is that it copies `*p` – and that is a `Foo&`, not a `Bar&`.

This adaptation of your last example would behave the same:

```
Bar b;
Foo& c = b;
std::function<int(void)> f1 = c;
std::cout << f1() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 12):

### Slicing

This is a case of slicing. 
The reason is assignment operator of `std::function` (as demonstrated in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57725063/2261538) as well) which states:

> Sets the target of *this to the callable f, as if by executing
>   function(std::forward(f)).swap(*this);. This operator does not
>   participate in overload resolution unless f is Callable for argument
>   types Args... and return type R. (since C++14)

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator%3D

If you simplify and strip down the example - you can easily see what's going on:

```
Foo* p =  new Bar;

Foo f;
f = *p;//<-- slicing here since you deref and then copy the object
```

It looks like you were aiming at obtaining a pointer to the overridden virtual function - unfortunately, theres no easy way to *unroll* the virtual function lookup as that is implemented via a *runtime* lookup table. However an easy workaround might be to use a lambda to wrap (As the OP also mentions):

```
f = [p]{return (*p)();};
```

A more suitable solution could also be to just a use `reference_wrapper`:

```
f = std::ref(p);
```

Comment: +1 for showing a workaround. However, the reason why this code "simplifies" to `Foo f = *p;` could use some more explanation.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't ask for a workaround. As I mentioned, I fixed the bug and actually I did it by a lambda. What I asked for is a detailed explanation.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Sure thing, I mentioned those workaround/solutions primarily for other users coming here. But I will update my answer.

Comment: Or [`std::ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) for short.

Answer (score 0):

The static type of the pointer `p` is `Foo`.

So in this statement

```
f = *p;
```

there left operand `*p` has the type `Foo` that is there is slicing.